# How to check that user has arrive the destination on Mapbox SDK?

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox, mapbox-ios

Is there any delegate method of Mapbox NavigationViewController that trigger when user arrive the destination? Because I found that when the destination really close with iPhone/user location, the map view of NavigationViewController will entire map. But when I tapped on the top banner of NavigationViewController to show route step then tapped again to dismiss the map was show as the MGLMapCamera was set. I've try to user method `navigationViewController(_ navigationViewController: NavigationViewController, didArriveAt waypoint: Waypoint) -> Bool` to check if iPhone/user reach the destination it will show a `showEndOfRouteFeedback` but it didn't work. This happen only the user location is really close to the destination, other case is work properly.

[image #1 shows that user has arrived the destination with full entire map.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G14dd.png)

[image #2 tap on NavViewController's top bar.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmUpL.png)

[image #3 After dismiss NavViewController's top bar.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEvCX.png)

Here is my code when user tap on the callout.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, tapOnCalloutFor annotation: MGLAnnotation) {
    guard let route = route, let routeOptions = routeOptions else { return }
    let navVC = NavigationViewController(for: route, routeIndex: 0, routeOptions: routeOptions)
    let camera = MGLMapCamera(lookingAtCenter: userCurrentLocation, altitude: 0, pitch: 0, heading: 0)
    navVC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    navVC.automaticallyAdjustsStyleForTimeOfDay = true
    navVC.pendingCamera = camera
    navVC.routeLineTracksTraversal = true
    self.present(navVC, animated: true, completion: nil) 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I just update all cocoapod in my project and run again.